# How to know the index of radiobutton selected

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, radio-button, silverlight-5.0

How to know the selcted index of a radio button to know which index option is selcted by user.

Currently my code displays the items read. But when i select the items appeared then it shows in a textblock the 
selected item of radiobutton (of the given 3 options, because my radiobutton currently has 3 items).

My try fo this is :

```
foreach (String item in param.Parameter[lop].Component.Attributes.Items)
{
    RadioButton radio = new RadioButton()
    {
        Content = item,
        GroupName = "MyRadioButtonGroup"
    };
    radio.Checked += (o, e) =>
    {
        txtblkShowStatus.Text = item;       
    };
    data= param.Parameter[lop].Label;
    sp.Children.Add(radio);                           
}
```

Now i want something like insted of "item" based selection now i want index based seelction.
I want some thing like . If user select 2nd button(of radiobutton) then i will display some UI element. And the items are obtained on deserializing an xml. Which only deals with the index of the radio buttons. So i want something like `if(selectedIndexofRadioButton ==IndexObtainedFromXmlInIntegr){do something}`

**Is it possible to do? If yes then how should i change my code to achieve this ?**
EDIT: My code change after DonBoitnott's answer edit is :

```
foreach (String item in param.Parameter[lop].Component.Attributes.Items)
                        {
                            RadioButton radio = new RadioButton()
                            {
                                Content = item,
                                GroupName = "MyRadioButtonGroup",
                                Tag=tg
                            };
                            radio.Checked += (o, e) =>
                            {
                                txtblkShowStatus.Text = item;
                                if (((Int32)((RadioButton)o).Tag).Equals(2))
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("hurrey");
                                }
                            };
                            radio.Tag=1;
                            data= param.Parameter[lop].Label;
                            sp.Children.Add(radio);
                            index++; tg++;
                        }
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for.  Index of what?  Radio buttons in a group don't have an index.  What is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: @DonBoitnott I want some thing like . If user select 2nd button(of radiobutton) then i will display some UI element. And the items are obtained on deserializing an xml. Which only deals with the index of the radio buttons. So i want something like if(selectedIndexofRadioButton ==IndexObtainedFromXmlInIntegr){do something}

Comment: Then use the `Tag` property to assign that index to each `RadioButton`.  Such as:  `radio.Tag = 1;`.  Then you can use that tag (cast to int) to test equality.

Comment: @DonBoitnott cold you please answer me below in detail so taht i would mark you as answer and would be useful for any user in future.

Comment: @DonBoitnott i don't know in advance that how many items i will have so i cant do " radiobutton1.Tag" , radiobutton2.Tag they will be decided dynamically. How to achieve now ?

Comment: In the code you posted, the loop, do you have the index at that point?  If so, then see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should leverage the `Tag` property of the `RadioButton` control object:

```
foreach (String item in param.Parameter[lop].Component.Attributes.Items)
{
    RadioButton radio = new RadioButton()
    {
        Content = item,
        GroupName = "MyRadioButtonGroup",
        Tag = //integer value from XML
    };
    radio.Checked += (o, e) =>
    {
        txtblkShowStatus.Text = item;       
    };
    data = param.Parameter[lop].Label;
    sp.Children.Add(radio);                           
}
```

The `Tag` property is an `Object`, so you can assign anything to it.  You just have to cast it on the way out when you use it:

```
if (((Int32)radioButton.Tag).Equals(IndexObtainedFromXmlInInteger)
{
    //do something
}
```

In response to your comment, OP:

```
radio.Checked += (o, e) => 
{
    txtblkShowStatus.Text = item; 
    if (((Int32)((RadioButton)o).Tag).Equals(2)) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hurrey");
    }
};
```

You are mistakenly trying to use `radio`, which is declared above.  Instead, use what the anonymous method *actually receives*, which is `o`, or the `Sender`.

Comment: let me try it .Will see if it wrks

Comment: May be you misunderstood me i tried this : radio.Checked += (o, e) =>
                            {
                                txtblkShowStatus.Text = item;
                                if (((Int32)radio.Tag).Equals(2))
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("hurrey");
                                }
                            }; I EXPECT IT TO PRINT A MESSAGE BOX WHEN THE THIRD BUTTON IN THE RADIOBUTTON is selcted..But nothing popups .

Comment: and when i change this "2" to "1" then it popups message box on all the three button clicks(because it still read "1" as true)

Comment: still the same ..Nothing popus

Comment: it worked it was my mistake i had kept radio.Tag=1; by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Create an event for when the index is changed on your radio button group.  After this create a separate function to deserialize your XML file.  Pass the given integer obtained from your XML file to the index changed event and then display the UI element accordingly.  Be sure to compare the integer on the .selectedIndex property of your radio button.

Comment: do radiobutton have index changed event ? in silverligth ?

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radbutton-features-radio-button.html          Have a look at that.  It should answer your questions about the radio button properties.

Comment: thanks but . i dont have to use telerik. do you know how to achieve it using "Tag" property ?

Comment: You would create a class or object to store your deserialized XML values and then assign the radio button that value using the tag property.  Something like: radiobutton1.Tag = new XMLValues()  where XMLValues are your deserialized integers.  Tag is not necessary to do what you want, but if that's the way you want to go then this is how I would do it.

Comment: i don't know in advance that how many items i will have so i cant do " radiobutton1.Tag" , radiobutton2.Tag they will be decided dynamically. How to achieve now ?

Comment: Can you not just create an array of a custom type and then assign the tag property to each item in it?  Something like:  List<CustomRadioButtonClass> radioButtons = new List<CustomRadioButtonClass>;  then once you have all of your radio buttons in there set the tag property like: foreach(var item in radioButtons) {item.Tag = new XMLValues();}  or you could pass the XML values in to an array and set the Tag property equal to the index of that array when iterating through the List.  I hope that makes sense.